# Using cAdvisor to monitor docker containers

Tags: docker, prometheus, cadvisor

I am planning to use cAdvisor to monitor performance of running docker container on multiple VMs, do I need to install cAdvisor on all VMs, or there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need it on each host seeing as it uses the local mounts to get the data it exports